# Availability Groups - When Does Synchronous Mode Actually Restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

Given the scenario where a connection for a synchronous replica of an AG is broken, 10 seconds (by default) elapse and the replica goes into asynchronous mode.  This allows database clients to keep writing and everyone is happy.

Then the connection is reestablished, and according to the documentation, it goes back into synchronous mode.  My question is, does it do this immediately, which would block clients from writing to the database until the replica is back in synch, or does it actually wait until it's almost synchronized before it goes back to synchronous mode?  If it goes back to synchronous mode immediately and it takes a few minutes for it to get back in synch, database write transactions will be held up for a few minutes--more "downtime."

I'm wanting to know so that if we have an extended outage on a node, we know whether we need to configure the replica as asynch so that we don't end up with more delays when the node comes back online.

Comment: Is the crux of the question whether you'll be forced into 2-phase commits immediately or not?

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft Yes--are any new attempts to write a transaction on the primary going to be delayed until the secondary gets in synch.

Comment: The database will be in the synchronizing state, so not it won't be a commit participant yet. Once the send queue unloads and the replica catches back up, it'll show as synchronized and then it'll start waiting on the sync commit. Not sure if that's enough explanation or not.